# Fantasy novel series where an orphaned boy living as a commoner regains his inheritance

Tags: story-identification, novel

Having just finished the Mageborn series by Michael G. Manning, I was reminded by the events in the first book, The Blacksmith's Son, of another fantasy novel series.

Here are the similarities that I remember:

- The Boy-child whisked away by a female warrior.
- Female warrior fighting pursuers and leaving some items for the boy with the commoner foster parents.
- The Boy is friends with the child/children of the local lord and visits the castle/keep.
- The Boy becomes a wizard.

It is quite possible that in a later books he visits a fantasy Arabic-like country, and in another there may be a sea-voyage, possibly even a stranding.

I cannot remember any more details, be it the publication date (definitively pre-2010), number of books in the series (<8;~5), ...

Comment: You title "orphaned boy living as a commoner regains his inheritance" matches only a few thousand books...

Comment: @GEdgar: That is why I have also given more details/information - a specific event. But perhaps you could tell me how I should have phrased the title?!

Comment: Sadly it's just not enough for me to get it.  In combination, the details might narrow it down, but all the tropes are common enough to make nailing down this one blend of them hard.  Focusing just on 'female rescuer', my mind pushed out both *Memory Sorrow and Thorn*, and *Kushiel's Legacy*, which are books so far opposite they shouldn't be in the same sentence.  Keep thinking about it, edit in more details if you can find some.

Comment: It's Harry Potter! No? (j/k to be clear)

Answer (score 1):

It's not [The Belgariad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Belgariad) by David Eddings, is it?

Polgara the Sorceress (daughter of Belgarath the Sorcerer who is 7,000 years old while she is a mere 3000), looks after Garion, the boy who was orphaned and is the rightful heir to the island kingdom of Riva.  She raises him as a commoner in a farm house.

Over the series of the five books, he meets various kings and queens, and later becomes not only a sorcerer called Belgarion but the King of Riva and the Overlord of the West and ultimately defeats the God Torak as the various kingdoms stage a huge battle.  One of the places they visit is Riva (so sea voyage).

Not sure if it's a perfect fit, but it was what immediately sprung to mind for me.

Comment: I thought of that too, but I wouldn't call Polgara a warrior, and the 2nd-3rd bullet points don't seem to fit at all.

Comment: @randal'thor I thought I'd throw it out there given that sometimes recollections of details can be a little hazy.

Comment: Sorry, but it is definitely not.

Comment: @MartinHandrlica No problem!  Trust me, I _know_ how hard it can be to get a match on these sometimes.  My very first question on this site was a [tag:story-identification] one and no-one was ever able to give me an answer :(

Comment: @JaneS Hmm... Mind if I put a bounty on that question? Will you be around to answer further questions?

Comment: @SQB Certainly I will be around! Thank you for caring about my question :)